# PHP PDO : Charset=UTF8 : An invalid keyword charset was specified in the dsn string

Tags: php, sql, character-encoding, pdo

I am connecting to an MS SQL server with PDO using the sqlsrv driver.

PHP version is 5.3.24.
The working connection looks like this:

```
$dsny = "sqlsrv:Server=xx1;Database=xx2";
$usery = 'xx3';
$passwordy = 'xx4';
$dbhy = new PDO($dsny, $usery, $passwordy);
```

**

But i need to set characters, and then i try this:

```
$dsny = "sqlsrv:Server=xx1;Database=xx2;charset=utf8";
$usery = 'xx3';
$passwordy = 'xx4';
$dbhy = new PDO($dsny, $usery, $passwordy);
```

When i add the charset i get this error:
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid keyword 'charset' was specified in the dsn string'"

So what could be causing this fault ?

From what i read i need to do like this since i am running a new PHP version.

Comment: I tried with both utf8, UTF8, utf-8, iso-8859-1, greek1, etc.. It seems like it is something about "charset" rather than the actual charset i try to set.

Comment: does sqlsrv DSN support this keyword?

Comment: You are correct. This is not the way to go. I was looking for a solution to set characters.

Answer (score 9):

You need to apply the attribute after connecting:

```
$dbhy->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628157(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Great answer. However, I already have two parameters in setAttribute and would like to add these as well. How can I add these two with what I already have since 2 parameters are only allowed? `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: You simply add another "setAttribute" line with the another parameter.