# Return JSON NULL

Tags: php, html, sql-server, json, pdo

I have a data encoding problem. My database has accents in one of the columns, in the api return that column in a PDO query SQL SERVER in php. As soon as I return I transform into JSON by the json_encode method, plus the JSON comes NULL. When I give var_dump the question letters with accents this appears '�' and in json empty.
I know it's the encoding I need to convert to UTF8 but I'm not able to do this conversion in php. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800915/php-pdo-charset-utf8-an-invalid-keyword-charset-was-specified-in-the-dsn-str

Comment: try `utf_encode()` and check. can you please also tell what are the original characters there?

Comment: <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

include_once '../../../config.php';
include_once '../api/helpdesk.php';
include_once '../api/conexaoSql.php';

require_login();

$codigo = $_GET['id'];

try {
$objHelp = new helpdesk();
$mensagens = $objHelp->SelecionaMensagem($codigo);
    
//var_dump($mensagens);
    
echo json_encode($mensagens, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}

Comment: Return is an array inside an array

Comment: 1) Convert from *what* encoding? It's like trying to convert 9.95 to American dollars, it doesn't make sense if you don't know the source currency. 2) If data is already corrupted before serialising to JSON, it's pointless to fix it after it's broken. You should go back to the design table and make sure your basic database connection is properly configured.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Are you specifying the header for the right charset?

`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Notice also that your columns and tables should be `utf8_unicode_ci`.

And finally your connection to database should also be set accordingly `charset=utf8`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted me less than 1 second after posting my answer: thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. this question has nothing to do with Content-type: text/html. Neither with mysql.

Comment: @YourCommonSense And you saw all that in less than 1 second. Cool.

Comment: Please avoid off topic discussions in comments

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sure boss, whatever you say.