# special character in php pdo sqlsrv not handled correctly

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

In my database I have an entry `CARIÑO` when I select it in database I get `CARIÃO` showing when I inspect element in browser. When I try to save it again in database I get error saying:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: `'\xC2\x91O'` for column
>   I want to know how to fix this error in a way that it will show `CARIÑO` in browser and be saved again as `CARIÑO` into database.

In my database connection I have:

```
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'mysql:charset=utf8mb4'); 
//Establishes the connection
$this->_connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=IP;Server=$serverName,1433; Database=".DB_NAME."",DB_USER,DB_PASS,$options);
```

I used sample in [stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for using the `mysql:charset=utf8mb4`

And in my select I have:

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     // $selected_row['column'] = $column;
     //echo $selected_row['patlast'];//this ouputs CARIÃO
     $rows1[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
     $rows[] =  array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
}
```

The database I select from is ms sql server.

`UPDATE:`

After running from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377812/getting-data-with-utf-8-charset-from-mssql-server-using-php-freetds-extension):

```
mb_detect_encoding($selected_row['patlast'], mb_detect_order(), true) === 'UTF-8' ?  $content= $selected_row['patlast'] :  $content= mb_convert_encoding($selected_row['patlast'], 'UTF-8');
echo "patlast: ".$content; // i get patlast: CARIÃ‘O
echo "mb_detect_encoding: ". mb_detect_encoding($selected_row['patlast'], mb_detect_order(), true);//i get mb_detect_encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: your database is not mysql so you cannot use mysql commands

Comment: @YourCommonSense what is ms sql equivalent for `mysql:charset=utf8mb4` is there an equivalent?

Comment: i dont know, i don't work with sqlsrv. but I am sure there should be existing answers for sqlsrv somewhere

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800915/php-pdo-charset-utf8-an-invalid-keyword-charset-was-specified-in-the-dsn-str

Comment: but what is strange, the error message you get looks like it's from mysql, not sql server

Comment: i saw that casting will work like `cast (patlast as nvarchar) as patlast` but it didnt. i am selecting from ms sql database @YourCommonSense

Comment: what i dont understand is when i select directly in microsoft sql server management studio i get the correct the value which is `CARIÑO` in system using php pdo i dont get the correct @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed :

```
$rows1[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
$rows[] =  array_map('utf8_encode', $selected_row);
```

To

```
$rows1[] = array_map(null, $selected_row);
$rows[] =  array_map(null, $selected_row);
```

Now gets the correct name `CARIÑO`